# Example of parallel sum algorithm on GPU

Tags: parallelism, gpu, webgl

Trying to imagine how you would go about implementing summation (or reduction?) on a parallel architecture and am having a difficult time.

Specifically thinking in terms of WebGL arrays of vectors such as this:

```
[integer1, integer2, integer3, ...]
```

Wondering if there is a way to do this in parallel

```
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... ]

var sum = 0
array.forEach(function(number){
  sum += number
})

return sum
```

The problem I am encountering is I think mentioned here in this NVidia document on GPU reduction (not quite following):

[how do we communicate partial results between thread blocks?](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf)

Wondering if one can describe an algorithm that computes the sum of something in parallel, since there is a shared variable that needs to be used somehow (the sum variable). Or perhaps this isn't possible.

Comment: dont they have the exact example on page 8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654754/how-to-find-the-sum-of-array-in-cuda-by-reduction

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you *don't* share the accumulator. You have a separate accumulator for each adder, and start each at `0`. The final step is to sum the results.

This generalises beyond arithmetic addition, as a parallel reducer will assume that it's arguments form a [Monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

> Suppose that `S` is a set and `•` is some binary operation `S × S →
>   S`, then `S` with `•` is a monoid if it satisfies the following two
>   axioms:
>
> - Associativity
>
>   - For all `a`, `b` and `c` in `S`, the equation `(a • b) • c = a • (b • c)` holds.
> - Identity element
>
>   - There exists an element `e` in `S` such that for every element `a` in `S`, the equations `e • a = a • e = a` hold.

Where `S` is the set of all values of a particular type, `•` is the operation, and the identity `e` is the initial value (or alternatively that a default instance of `S` is `e`)

Comment: Thank you. I understand what a Monoid is. Wondering what you mean by "You have a separate accumulator for each adder, and start each at 0. The final step is to sum the results." Wondering if that final step must be done sequentially/in parallel, and how that would look (and not sure what the adder/accumulator are). Would love an example such as in WebGL/GLSL.